# Neo4j - Dijkstra algorithm with full path evaluation

Tags: java, neo4j, traversal, dijkstra

I have a neo4j database with weighted paths, where the total weight calculation depends on the path as a whole. For example, some nodes may provide "credit" which offsets future weight but not weight earlier in the path (so it can't just be summed).

The Dijkstra algorithm seems like the right starting point. If the entire path required to get to each node is stored, then that path plus the new segment can be evaluated to get a cost to reach a new node. Unfortunately, the CostEvaluator only wants to work for a segment at a time. Is there a reasonable way to repurpose the code in this manner?